# Передача потока данных через интернет

Tags: delphi, indy, сокет

Добрый день!

Я научился передавать текстовые сообщения по локальной сети с помощью компонентов сокетов (`Sockets`). Как научиться передавать потоки данных (текстовые или файловые или может быть даже записи) через интернет между двумя удаленными компьютерами имеющие программы `client` и `server` (а не через локальную сеть)?

Поделитесь ссылками, кусками кода или исходниками на эту тему. Либо как вариант как организовать через `Indy` компоненты передачу потока данных (текстовые данные, числовые, файловые)?

Comment: Работа с инди компонентами: http://pro.dtn.ru/delphi-net/1-net.html

Answer (score 2):

Передача данных через сеть интернет с использованием компонентов TTCPClient/Server происходит именно также как и в Ethernet, за исключением настройки оборудования "общающихся" узлов, а именно настройка брандмауеров, роутеров и т.п.

У tcpClient.Socket есть метод sendBuf, который и используется для передачи "не только текста", делфей под рукой нет, не могу код набросать к сожалению, но копать тебе нужно в сторону справки, на сколько я помню там всё достаточно подробно описано!

Comment: спасибо за ответ... Да действительно у TCPClient.Socket есть один из методов SendBuf, который фрагменты буфера позволяет передавать. Где эту справку найти? В самом делфи что ли? Есть ли в Delphi XE или 7 исходники-демки по работе с инди и сокетами?

Comment: Да есть демки: %PROGRAMFILES%\Borland\Delphi7\Demos\Internet\NetChat

И в справке есть, достаточно на SendBuf кликнуть по кнопке F1 и выбрать соответствующий раздел справки (Delphi 7).

По сути компоненты Indy (TIdTCPClient/Server) работают как раз через сокеты, только механизмы работы с ними более совершенны по сравнению с TTCPClient/Server, например соединения там поднимаются в отдельных потоках.

Comment: спасибо, поищу в 7. В делфи XE не нашел что-то папки demos.

Answer (score 2):

```
clSock.Address :=''; //Указать адрес сервера, например '76.74.38.41' 
clSock.Port:=777; //номер порта, например 777
clSock.Active:=True;
//Готов к работе только после OnWrite

ClSock.Socket.ReceiveBuf(BufIn,Cnt+4);
//Для приема лучше использовать OnRead
ClSock.Socket.SendBuf(BufOut,i3+4);
```

Comment: ClSock - это в данном случае какой компонент?

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего реализовать простейший протокол обмена информации, т.е. как-то упорядочить процесс передачи и контролировать его.

Comment: мне кажется нецелесообразным создавать свой протокол, это равносильно изобретать свой велосипед, когда есть хорошо отлаженные и популярные TCP, UDP.

Answer (score 0):

в Самом *Delphi* есть готовый исходник чата, NetChat называется.

Там показано как работать с `TCPServer` и `TCPClient` из `Indy`

Можете его использовать. Но проблема не в этом, нужно как то двум клиентам передать их адреса (реальные `IP` адреса). Для этого обычно нужен сервер